# Use regexp to check and save phone number

Tags: python, regex

I want to check for Russian/Kazahstan mobile phones (starts with +7 9x or +7 7x), but `re` sintaxis completely blow my mind.
I want to accept numbers in such formats:

```
+7 9XX XXXXXXX 
+7 7XX XXXXXXX 
7 7XX XXXXXXX
7 9XX XXXXXXX
8 9XX XXXXXXX   (8 is domestic replace for country code)
8 7XX XXXXXXX  
9XX XXXXXXX     (9 numbers, no country code!)
7XX XXXXXXX
```

and save them in `7XXXXXXXXXX` format(**country code** + 10 numbers, without **+**)

I wrote this:
`re.search(r'^(\+?79?|\+?77?|89?|87?|9|7)(\d{9})$','+79221234567').groups()`

How I can save results in needed format now? Should I wrote another regexp which I will apply to result of regexp above (`re.search('(\d{10})$',result_above)`), or there is better way to get formatted result in one regexp expression?

P.S.: My regexp works for numbers, but if I input number with - or (), it will fail. Can I avoid that?

Comment: My advice for phone numbers is, let the users enter whatever symbols they want. Then strip anything nonnumeric and verify that it has the correct number of digits and the correct digits. Then store only the numbers in the db. Now you'll have consistency and *you* can format it however you want when displaying it back to the user.

Comment: For example, for a US number, it can be in any format like: `+1 XXX-XXX-XXXX`, `(XXX) XXX-XXXX`, `XXX-XXX-XXXX`, etc. I don't care. I strip anything that's not a number, and check: `1?(\d{10})` (10 digits preceded by an optional 1). Then I store just the 10 digits, and now I can format it to my liking.

Comment: That is what I'm trying to do. I only check that number starts with 7 or 9 (besides country code). In my question I ask how to strip user's input and make it ready for save :)

Comment: I would do something like: `re.search(r'^([7-9])?([79]\d{9})$', re.sub(r'\D+', '', number)).groups()`

Comment: `re.search(r'^\+?[78]?([79]\d{9})$','+79231234567')` works almost like I want (thnx NullUserException!), except **+**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It may be helpful to see how [Google Android](http://code.google.com/p/libphonenumber/) does this task. It is the same library used by Google Talk, Facebook, Android, etc.

The Android library itself is not Python, but the [concepts](https://docs.google.com/presentation/d/1XJtew6w0_k-3oeN_w2edNqRFZgPGrjssSAGup_JLa5k/present#slide=id.i0) carry over. There is an actively maintained parallel [Python port](https://github.com/daviddrysdale/python-phonenumbers) of the same library.

You can play with a [Javascript version of it](http://libphonenumber.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/javascript/i18n/phonenumbers/demo.html) to see if this fits your needs.

Trying to robustly parse a non-trivial phone number with a regex is hard. There are gazillions of variants. I recommend finding and using a good library.

Comment: Thanks for link with JS, looks promising. I saw it before, but though it only save and format numbers, not validate them. Maybe it is even better than regex for my project :)

Answer (score 0):

Going off what NullUserException and ilya said, here's an example:

#### Read in information from user and strip out anything besides numbers:

```
import re
phone_num = raw_input("Phone number. номер телефона\n)

only_nums = int(''.join(re.findall(r'\d', phone_num)))
```

#### Check for 7 or 9 starting condition:

```
if only_nums[0] == 7 || only_nums[0] == 9:
  print only_nums
```